# React-router-dom Link changes URL without rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a `Main` component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import store from '../store';
import history from '../store/history';

import SideBar from './SideBar';
import { ConnectedUsers } from './UsersPage';

const Main = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <SideBar/>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/users"
          render={ () => (<ConnectedUsers/>)}
        />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  </Router>
);

export default Main;
```

It uses a navigation component which I've named `SideBar`:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

const SideBar = () => (
  <div>
    <Link to="/users">
      <h1>Users</h1>
    </Link>
  </div>
);

export default SideBar;
```

This doesn't work. When I click on the Users link on the page in the browser, the URL changes to the correct one (localhost:8080/users) but the page remains blank. The component doesn't render. If I put the URL `localhost:8080/users` manually in the address bar in the browser the component renders correctly.

After some searches, I found people recommending to implement the routes like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import store from '../store';
import history from '../store/history';

import SideBar from './SideBar';
import { ConnectedUsers } from './UsersPage';

const Main = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <SideBar/>
        <Route exact path="/users" component={withRouter(ConnectedUsers)}
        />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  </Router>
);

export default Main;
```

But this also didn't work for me. The exact same propblem remains—the `/users` page renders correctly when I manually type in the URL in the address bar, but comes up blank if I navigate to that URL using the `Link`.

Comment: `<Route exact path="/users" component={withRouter(ConnectedUsers)} />` will be the same, anything directly rendered by a `Route` receives the route-props. Can you post up a running codesandbox that reproduces this issue? Have you tried using one of the more high-level routers, like `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @brijesh-pant There is only one route, so the `Switch` should have no effect. Also, react-router-dom *does* actually export a `Router`.

Comment: Yeah, `BrowserRouter` did the trick. Now everything is working. Thank you, Drew Reese. What is `Router` for then?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Router "The common low-level interface for all router components. Typically app will use one of the high-level routers instead. ... The most common use-case for using the low-level `<Router>` is to synchronize a custom history with a state management lib like Redux or Mobx. ..."